# Could not exec the linker `cc` error when running "cargo build"

Tags: macos, linker, rust, rust-cargo

I just installed Rust on my Mac and `rustc --version --verbose` displays

```
rustc 1.0.0-nightly (91bdf23f5 2015-03-09) (built 2015-03-08)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: 91bdf23f504f79ed59617cde3dfebd3d5e39a476
commit-date: 2015-03-09
build-date: 2015-03-08
host: x86_64-apple-darwin
release: 1.0.0-nightly
```

I cloned a couple of repositories ([postgres-extension](https://github.com/thehydroimpulse/postgres-extension.rs) and [erlang-rust-nif](https://github.com/lavrin/erlang-rust-nif)) and ran `cargo build` upon both of them. Both reported the error

```
error: could not exec the linker `cc`: No such file or directory (os error 2)
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Additionally, I wasn't able to compile a simple Rust file printing `"hello world"` using rustc.  I was only able to compile them by passing the flags `rustc -C linker=gcc hello_world.rs`.

`clang --version` displays

```
clang version 3.4.2  (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 5c6aa738fb3325ae499454877f1e2926d2368135)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
Thread model: posix
```

`gcc --version` displays

```
gcc (Homebrew gcc49 4.9.2_1) 4.9.2
```

Comment: What does `which cc` return?

Comment: Currently I have made an `alias` in my `.bash_profile` as `alias cc=gcc`. Hence it returns nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you have installed GCC and LLVM/clang via Homebrew. Checking out the [shared macOS configurations](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/dd077d5decbc3e462a9fe2feb1a0af0486897acb/src/librustc_back/target/apple_base.rs#L18), the linker defaults to `cc`. I have installed the macOS developer tools:

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix

$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix

$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

This is potentially something that Rust itself could fix, but you'd have to file a bug report / enhancement request. It's possible that you might be able to work around this by symlinking `clang` as `cc`, instead of just aliasing it, as aliases probably don't exist in the environment that Rust is calling out from.

Comment: I reinstalled `llvm` and `gcc` through OSX Command Line Tools and it worked fine.

Comment: As @abips did in OSX, I installed gcc in LInux and it resolved this problem.

Comment: For posterity, the problem was fixed on debian by `sudo apt-get install gcc`