# Unable to compile for Linux on an Intel Mac

Tags: c, linux, unix, rust, compilation

I'm running MacOS on Intel and getting the following error when I try to compile with targets: `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu`, `i686-unknown-linux-gnu` and `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.

```
$ sudo cargo deb --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
warning: license field is missing in Cargo.toml
   Compiling libc v0.2.137
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling parking_lot_core v0.9.4
   Compiling lock_api v0.4.9
   Compiling log v0.4.17
   Compiling smallvec v1.10.0
   Compiling scopeguard v1.1.0
   Compiling serde v1.0.145
   Compiling memchr v2.5.0
   Compiling indexmap v1.9.1
   Compiling hashbrown v0.12.3
   Compiling tokio v1.22.0
   Compiling ryu v1.0.11
   Compiling mio v0.8.5
   Compiling socket2 v0.4.7
   Compiling signal-hook-registry v1.4.0
   Compiling parking_lot v0.12.1
   Compiling num_cpus v1.14.0
   Compiling itoa v1.0.3
   Compiling pin-project-lite v0.2.9
   Compiling unsafe-libyaml v0.2.4
   Compiling bytes v1.2.1
   Compiling serde_yaml v0.9.14
   Compiling demoprj v0.1.0 (/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-m64" "/tmp/rustc5zB91z/symbols.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.14.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.15.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.server.eaf65156-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a.k84j6jkazra99rc.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps" "-L" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/release/deps" "-L" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libserde_yaml-40a090efcb6e3ca1.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libryu-525bd9b4a541cd1e.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libitoa-a7f49c8af29a3048.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libindexmap-01cff7c36445293e.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libhashbrown-816ca2e34f0825a6.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libunsafe_libyaml-fde97438592a42ff.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libserde-0f92570efc48b240.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtokio-78e7d69c8b30a7dc.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libsignal_hook_registry-bda84cc3e2cf0248.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libnum_cpus-c27edd3d8290acc6.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libsocket2-7e6e2e63fdbf6338.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libmemchr-da3f0164a4504a7e.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libbytes-07d33d5e9a6840e8.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libmio-8c86ee07666a60ca.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liblog-2dcd1b97cacb7972.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libpin_project_lite-d035bd2af876e5fe.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libparking_lot-590e841de40d59e8.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libparking_lot_core-8ac6b80dbfa8f66f.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liblibc-3e87f785f32dccdb.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libcfg_if-c7e466740d7e05f2.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libsmallvec-0326b983044ebf85.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liblock_api-e2917566a951e90f.rlib" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libscopeguard-85179ca1007a17a4.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-05737cf45bd30456.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-9f873b61fdec9b03.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-7f13930fcac1846f.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-098633b847612f3b.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-f14b73d282b0245e.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-2c5b4433ebc1d822.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-59591a7b405fe395.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-384947c6d5f697ff.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-b08a86c6880b47a8.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-58adeee671f9ba8e.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-f156b880fc73e7f0.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-4458c5022988e1ab.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-02e61e5ec4aa9e8b.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-a0d9b33b5161957b.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-04cec55a79224c36.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-3fb6d8496dc7d6a6.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-7d46c016841a97d4.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-a1f7b8b60464cc57.rlib" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-272ca28f0b8538d5.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-znoexecstack" "-L" "/Users/boris/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/Users/b/o/d/rust/demoprj/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/server-f69841404ba8121a" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro,-znow" "-Wl,-O1" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
          ld: unknown option: --as-needed
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
          

error: could not compile `demoprj` due to previous error
cargo-deb: build failed
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Getting the same error with `cargo build --target=...` and `cargo deb --target=...`

Comment: Looks like not using the correct program for linking. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/29023305/1216776  Also, congrats on having the longest line I've seen in an SO question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cross compile from Mac to Linux?](/q/41761485/2189130) From comments there, you may need to install a different linker and tell cargo to use it.